# Problem with expression in xPath jsel library

Tags: javascript, xpath, expression

I have an issue with jsel, a library which uses xPath expressions to evaluate data.
I am trying to validate this expression: '//Pregnancy != true()' against a data object and I always have false as my result. For example the expression '//Sex != "f"' works perfect. I am using a custom schema for the jsel dom object. The question is why doesn't '//Pregnancy != true()' never returns true if Pregnancy is 'false' or false or null?

```
 const data = {
    "DoBirth": {
      "value": null,
      "unit": null,
      "isUnknown": false
    },
    "Sex": {
      "value": "m",
      "unit": null,
      "isUnknown": false
    },
    "Pregnancy": {
      "value": false,
      "unit": null,
      "isUnknown": false,
    }
  }

const schema = {
  nodeValue: function (node) {

    if (node['value'] != undefined) {
      return node['value'];
    }
    return node;
  }
}

  const dom = jsel(formData);
  dom.schema(schema)

const result = dom.select('//Pregnancy != true()')

//result = always false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XPath 1.0, `//Pregnancy != true()` is comparing a node-set to a boolean, and the rules for that comparison are that it means `boolean(//Pregnancy) != true()`, which is true only if there are no Pregnancy elements in the document.

I don't actually know how JSEL maps your Javascript objects to XML, but I would imagine that using the string `"true"` is more reliable than using the boolean `true()`.

You also need to be aware that in XPath, `//Sex != "f"` is true if there is a `Sex` element whose value is not "f". It's more likely that you want `not(//Sex = "f")` which is true if there is no `Sex` element whose value is "f".